# It is possible to use same host in different namespaces on Openshift Origin?

Tags: rest, openshift, devops, openshift-origin

I have some projects that respond on same host but different path.
I want to keep them separated in Openshift.
Ie.:

First service

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Route
metadata:
  name: first-api
  namespace: first-api
  labels:
    app: first-api
spec:
  host: api.com.br
  path: /first
  to:
    kind: Service
    name: first-api
  port:
    targetPort: tcp-8080
```

Second setvice

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Route
metadata:
  name: second-api
  namespace: second-api
  labels:
    app: second-api
spec:
  host: api.com.br
  path: /second
  to:
    kind: Service
    name: second-api
  port:
    targetPort: tcp-8080
```

Comment: take a look at https://docs.openshift.org/latest/architecture/core_concepts/routes.html#path-based-routes that might help you

Comment: As long as you don't add a host only route the separation should work.
Do you have added the both routes or do you have more the this two routes? What's the output of **oc get route** in your namespace/project?

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to do this by setting "InterNamespaceAllowed" on the ingresscontroller. This is done by running the following command:

```
oc -n openshift-ingress-operator patch ingresscontroller/default --patch '{"spec":{"routeAdmission":{"namespaceOwnership":"InterNamespaceAllowed"}}}' --type=merge
```

For more info, see: https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/4.10/networking/routes/route-configuration.html#nw-route-admission-policy_route-configuration

Answer (score 0):

There are security restrictions enforced in the OpenShift router that prevent hosts in different namespaces from overlapping (the oldest route "claims" the name).  We'd like to add more flexibility to disable this check in the future.

Answer (score 0):

This `HostAlreadyClaimed` error occurs usually in manually specified host names (defined using `spec.host` in Route configs). If you let host names to be created automatically, `HAProxy` will never create such name collisions.